# Unable to load sentiment model

Tags: stanford-nlp

**ERROR**

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve
>   "edu/stanford/nlp/models/sentiment/sentiment.ser.gz" as either class
>   path, filename or URL

**CODE**

```
 String text = "I am feeling very sad and frustrated.";
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("pos.model", "edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/wsj-bidirectional/wsj-0-18-bidirectional-distsim.tagger");
       // props.put("sentiment.model", "/Users/Prateek/Downloads/stanford-corenlp-models-current.jar");
        props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, parse, sentiment");
```

**jars used** 
stanford-corenlp-3.2.0-model.jar
stanford-corenlp-3.5.2.jar

Answer (score 0):

Your models jar and code jar versions are mismatched. You're using the code from version 3.5.2 and the models from version 3.2.

Comment: I am not getting the right jars, can u provide me the jars or the link to the jars?

Comment: You can just download the latest jars from the website: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html